# Adding a unique shape and color to QC points overlaid on a box-plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

[image]
[boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVimY.png)

I am trying to reproduce the image above. I am close but I cannot get the control values to have both a unique shape and color while staying with the case values. I assume that this was done with a clever use of a factor variable but I have no idea how they did it.

```
library(ggplot2)

box.print <- function(C1M,C1, D2, QCDC2, QCSDT4, num){
  NAME <- names(D2[num])
  adjsdt4 <- C1M[,num]
  sdt4 <- C1[,num]
  disco2 <- D2[,num]
  qcdc <- QCDC2[,num]
  qcsdt4 <- QCSDT4[,num]
  adj <- data.frame(Intensity=c(adjsdt4,qcsdt4),
                    Study= rep("adjSDT4",length(adjsdt4)+length(qcsdt4)),
                    QC= c(rep("cases",length(adjsdt4)),rep("QC",length(qcsdt4)))

  )
  nadj <- data.frame(Intensity=c(sdt4,qcsdt4),
                     Study= rep("SDT4",length(sdt4)+length(qcsdt4)),
                     QC= c(rep("cases",length(sdt4)),rep("QC",length(qcsdt4)))

  )
  disco <- data.frame(Intensity=c(disco2,qcdc),
                      Study= rep("DISCO2",length(disco2)+length(qcdc)),
                      QC= c(rep("cases",length(disco2)),rep("QC",length(qcdc)))

  )
  full <- rbind(adj,nadj,disco)

  g1 <- ggplot(full, aes(x=Study, y=Intensity))+geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)+ggtitle(NAME)+
    geom_jitter(alpha=0.5, aes(color=Study,label=Study,shape=QC),position = position_jitter(width = .8),size=2)
  g1 = g1+theme(panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor= element_blank(),
                panel.background= element_blank(),
                panel.border= element_rect(colour="black",fill=NA),
                legend.position="none")
  g1= g1+scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,1))+scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE)
  print(g1)
}

A <- data.frame(rnorm(100))
B <- data.frame(rnorm(100))
C <- A*2
QA <- data.frame(1.951, 1.734, 1.519, 1.397, 1.391, 1.825)
QA <- t(QA)
QC <- QA*1.5

box.print(A,B,C,QA,QC,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add another variable for color in the dataframe. You have a two value variable for the shape aesthetic, and you need a four value variable for the color aesthetic. Taking your sample function, create a variable for color:

```
box.print <- function(C1M,C1, D2, QCDC2, QCSDT4, num){
  NAME <- names(D2[num])
  adjsdt4 <- C1M[,num]
  sdt4 <- C1[,num]
  disco2 <- D2[,num]
  qcdc <- QCDC2[,num]
  qcsdt4 <- QCSDT4[,num]
  adj <- data.frame(Intensity=c(adjsdt4,qcsdt4),
                    Study= rep("adjSDT4",length(adjsdt4)+length(qcsdt4)),
                    QC= c(rep("cases",length(adjsdt4)),rep("QC",length(qcsdt4))))
  nadj <- data.frame(Intensity=c(sdt4,qcsdt4),
                 Study= rep("SDT4",length(sdt4)+length(qcsdt4)),
                 QC= c(rep("cases",length(sdt4)),rep("QC",length(qcsdt4))))
  disco <- data.frame(Intensity=c(disco2,qcdc),
                  Study= rep("DISCO2",length(disco2)+length(qcdc)),
                  QC= c(rep("cases",length(disco2)),rep("QC",length(qcdc))))
  full <- rbind(adj,nadj,disco)
  full$color <- NA
  full$color[full$QC == "QC"] <- "QC"
  full$color[full$QC == "cases"] <- full$Study[full$QC == "cases"]

  g1 <- ggplot(full, aes(x=Study, y=Intensity))+
                geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)+
                ggtitle(NAME)+
                geom_jitter(alpha=0.5, aes(color=color,label=Study, shape=QC),position = position_jitter(width = .8),size=2)

  g1 = g1+theme(panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor= element_blank(),
            panel.background= element_blank(),
            panel.border= element_rect(colour="black",fill=NA),
            legend.position="none")
  g1= g1+
      scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,1))+
      scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE) + 
      scale_color_manual(values = c("dodgerblue", "red", "darkgreen", "black"))
  print(g1)
}
```

It should produce something like this:
[Link to img since I can't embed yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnifj.png)